# What is the policy for editing the same question twice?

Tags: discussion

I ran into a minor dilemma recently.  I was attempting to fix some major grammatical and spelling errors in a question, only to realize that I had missed several important mistakes!

In my case, my edit was replaced by an edit by the original author so it didn't matter, but suppose my edit had gone through and I was given the +2 rep.  At that point, I would want to finish my edit (edit the same question again) but I wouldn't care about the reputation.

Despite my intentions, would this be seen as some kind of exploit or reputation farming and thus be penalized or prevented?  What is the policy on editing a question in immediate succession?

Comment: Cf. [_Muphry's law_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, it's best to proof read your edits a couple of times to make sure that you have got everything first time round.  However, if you see more things later on then there are a couple of possible scenarios:

1. You spot your omissions within 5 minutes of your edit being approved - in which case the system would automatically merge them due to the grace period.  In essence this is only counted as one edit so you wouldn't gain rep twice.
2. Your edit is *improved* by the reviewers, meaning that the problems you missed are fixed (assuming the approvers are proof reading too).  You only get the reputation if they mark your original edit as helpful, which they should be doing if it was.  Again you wouldn't get the reputation twice.
3. You edit on top of your previous edit.  As long as you are still fixing major errors in the post (i.e. not a minor edit) then this should also be approved by peer review.  I do not know if this would give duplicate rep (and I don't have an account in the right range to try) but as long as it is a rare occurrence (following the best practice of proof reading your changes in their entirety) I would be extremely doubtful it would be met with any repercussions from moderators.

Overall, it's best to simply avoid the situation by ensuring that if you're taking the time to edit, just take a bit longer to check that everything that should be fixed has been fixed first time.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I had proofread the changes, but I missed some obvious errors! (Then again, there were so many errors, I probably should've just left it to be closed.  It was nearly unintelligible.)

Answer (score 4):

If you edit within 5 minutes again it will cause it to merge with your original edit. If you edit again after that 5 minutes, you will get rep again. I believe these are reviewed and removed if they aren't sufficiently helpful.

Comment: Ah, so no automatic flags would be triggered?  Even if *both* were accepted edits?

Comment: If the first edit and the second edit both go into the queue and are both approved, @BlackVegetable will get +2 rep from each.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I stand corrected.